# Obtain IP address of a website using the Selenium package

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to build a list of websites which contain the Domain, title, and IP addresses. I figured out how to perform this using the `requests` module but I cannot seem to locate if the `selenium` modules can perform a similar feat. All guides point towards using selenium with proxies instead of identifying the hosts ip address.

using requests

```
import reqeusts
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = 'https://www.google.com'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--lang=en')
WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriver_source,chrome_options=options)

try:
    resp = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=True,timeout = 5,strem = True)
    resp.raise_for_status()

    ipaddress = resp.raw._connection.sock.socket.getsockname()
    miso_soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content)

    isoup = miso_soup.find('html')
    if isoup is not None:
        if isoup.find('title') is not None:
            Title = isoup.find('title').text 
        else:
            Title = isoup.find('meta',{'property':'og:title'})

    data = {'StatusCode':resp.status_code,'URL':resp.url,'Title':Title,'IPAddress':ipaddress}

except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    print(e)

    WebDriver.get(url)

    try:
        cur_url = WebDriver.current_url
        miso_soup = BeautifulSoup(self.WebDriver.page_source)
        ipaddress = ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

        isoup = miso_soup.find('html')
        if isoup is not None:
            if isoup.find('title') is not None:
                Title = isoup.find('title').text 
            else:
                Title = isoup.find('meta',{'property':'og:title'})        

        data = {'StatusCode':e.response.status_code,'URL':cur_url,'Title':Title,,'IPAddress':ipaddress}
    except:
        data = {'StatusCode':None,'URL':None,'Title':None,,'IPAddress':None}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Exactly what I mentioned in the post though. I want to find the IP address of a domain using selenium. Some websites refuse requests if there is no browser performing the request and as Selenium is an emulated browser, It can get around these request refusals.